# how to partitioning mysql by column value "user_id" and "gps_time"?

Tags: mysql, partition

my table scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `his_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `gps_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`his_id`,`user_id`)
)
```

I want partitioning this table by **user_id** and **gps_time**,
which column **user_id** is partitioned by first character A~Z、a~z、0~9,
column **gps_time** is partitioned by the tast 3 month(ie:3 partitions).

how to do that?
thanks alot~

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL 5.5, you can use multiple columns with RANGE partitioning.

From your question, it's not entirely clear how many partitions you want; it sounds as if you want a whole boatload of partitions, but I don't believe that's what you really want.

The syntax for RANGE partitioning is in the MySQL Reference Manual, available online.

here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html

(Be sure you check the manual for the version of MySQL you are actually running; there's been some significant changes to partitioning in 5.0, 5.1, 5.5, etc.

With MySQL 5.5.x, if you want a separate partitions for the first character of user_id, and a range of gps_time values, you could do something like this:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(userid, gps_time) 
( PARTITION pA0 VALUES LESS THAN ('B','2014-07-01')
, PARTITION pA1 VALUES LESS THAN ('B','2014-08-01')
, PARTITION pA2 VALUES LESS THAN ('B','2014-09-01')
, PARTITION pA3 VALUES LESS THAN ('B',MAXVALUE)

, PARTITION pB0 VALUES LESS THAN ('C','2014-07-01')
, PARTITION pB1 VALUES LESS THAN ('C','2014-08-01')
, PARTITION pB2 VALUES LESS THAN ('C','2014-09-01')
, PARTITION pB3 VALUES LESS THAN ('C',MAXVALUE)

, ...

, PARTITION pMX VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE,MAXVALUE),
```

But that'd be over 100 partitions. I can't imagine a scenario where that's that's you really want. (I'm not sure what the upper limit on partitions for a table is.)

---

With MySQL 5.1, I don't believe it's possible to partition on multiple columns. You could, howerver, partition on just the user_id column, and then create subpartitions (within each partition) on the gps_time column... but I've never done that before.